# Is there a function to convert a trigonmetric expression to an algebraic expression suitable for ComplexPlot?

Tags: functions, function-construction, complex

According to H. A Priesley:

"both $cosθ$ and $sinθ$ can be written as simple algebraic functions of
$z$":

$cosθ =\frac{1}{2} (z + \frac{1}{z}) \tag1$
$sinθ =\frac{1}{2i} (z − \frac{1}{z})\tag2$

Which is very handy but I'm not sure what function will convert say $\frac{\sinh(ax)}{\sinh(bx)}\,$ ot $ \frac{x\cos ax}{1+x^2}\coth \frac{\pi x}{4}$ to similar algebraic functions.  The only function I can find is TrigtoExp, but this does not include the needed  substution $ z = \exp iθ$ to work with function ComplexPlot.

Q1. Is there a function to convert a trigonmetric expression to an algebraic expression suitable for ComplexPlot?

Q2. If not what is the best way to get around this?

Comment: `Sinh[a x]/Cosh[b x] /. {a x -> Log[za], b x -> Log[zb]}`  gives an algebraic expression in $z_a$ and $z_b$, where, of course, $z_a = e^{a x}$, etc.

Comment: @LouisB thank you I'll try that.

Comment: `Sinh[a x]/Cosh[b x] /. x -> Log[z] // TrigToExp` also gives an algebraic expression.  May want to apply `Simplify` as well.

Comment: @LouisB what about more general terms invoving $\cos x$ or $\log x$ such as $\frac{\sin (ax)}{e^{\pi x} \sinh(\pi x)}$ or $\frac{x\log{\sin{(x)}}}{\sin(x)}$?